# LaTeX commands to type > (greater than) and < (less than) in KaTeX

Tags: youtrack, katex

Youtrack and many other web apps use KaTeX to render mathematical notation and markdown for all other things.

However markdown parser treats certain characters in a special way and interferes with KaTeX.

For example the following equation

```
\begin{equation}
X_i = \begin{cases}
0, t_i < t_{i-1} \\
1, (t_i - t_{i-1}) > t_0 \\
X_{i-1}, otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Would render incorrectly as

[image: incorrect rendering]

Note the missing line.

The reason is that `<` and `>` and the text between are treated as an HTML tag and thus ignored.

The intended rendering would instead look like

[image: correct rendering]

Reordering the cases resolves the issue as well as replacing `<` with `\leq` and `>` with `\geq`. But both solutions seem incomplete and in the latter case change the meaning of the equation.

In LaTeX there are no predefined commands for `<` and `>` and KaTeX currently does not support `\newcommand` yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/668111/13523) on tex stackexchange. And while it was closed there as off-topic, users provided a solution in comments. Using `\lt` for `<` and `\gt` for `>` is supported in KaTeX. So the equation should be typed as

```
\begin{equation}
X_i = \begin{cases}
0, t_i \lt t_{i-1} \\
1, (t_i - t_{i-1}) \gt t_0 \\
X_{i-1}, otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```